# Can DevForce 2010 do data migrations?

Tags: sql-server, devforce

I'm looking to perform some data model (schema) migrations in our database and we use DevForce 2010. Is there any built-in support for doing schema migrations in DevForce 2010, or am I going to have to script this by hand ?

Answer (score 0):

DevForce itself doesn't include support for schema migrations, but if you're using a Code First model you can use EF's built-in support for Code First Migrations.